# solve for soultion of one PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To solve second linear PDE, $u_{xx}-tu_{tt}-\frac{1}{2}u_t=0,t>0$, use the following transformation of the independent variables to derive a new PDE

$\zeta=x+2\sqrt{t},\eta=x-2\sqrt{t}$

And solve the resulting PDE (make use of d'Alembert's solution).  Find the solution of the original PDE that satisfies the following initial condition

$u(x,0)=\frac{x^2}{2},\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0.$

I have trouble applying the last initial condition, who could please help me out with this question? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is "the following transformation"?

Comment: I modified the question. Thanks for asking

Comment: Dear David, when I perform the given transformation, I find the PDE $4\partial_{\rho \eta} u + 1/2(\partial_\rho u - \partial_\eta u) = 0$. Do you agree with that?